# Columns is not generating during code-generation in records

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

Sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.17.0.xsd">
    <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
    <jdbc>
        <driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url></url>
        <user></user>
        <password></password>
    </jdbc>

    <!--  onError SILENT can be used with MYSQLDatabase for Memsql  -->
    <!-- <onError>SILENT</onError> -->
    <generator>
        <generate>
            <records>true</records>
            <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
            <generatedAnnotation>true</generatedAnnotation>
            <generatedAnnotationType>DETECT_FROM_JDK</generatedAnnotationType>
        </generate>
```

Earlier this file generated jOOQ code with records, and had columns. Now code generated but jooq-columns are not present

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a regression in the `MemSQLDatabase`, probably introduced with jOOQ 3.16's support for computed columns: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13854